# Target a checkbox status using css

Tags: css

I need to display the section based on the chckbox..for that i write through css

```
input[type = "checkbox"]:checked .sec-visible{ display : block; }
```

its working on ff, but not working on ie..any solution?

Comment: any chance you could post the code, and use the methods stack overflow offers? It's awfully difficult to read your code the way it is right now.

Answer (score 1):

You have the selector a little muddled, you need to select the input with its class then the type:

```
input.sec-visible[type="checkbox"]:checked
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/Q4XZP/2/).

Comment: At the time of checkbox enable..i need to display some section into visible condition

Comment: You want to display more HTML when the checkbox is enabled? If so, you'll need some jQuery which I can whip up for you.